# Swap FN modifier for a particular key

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have recently bought a new laptop and I have a keyboard "steelseries". The keyboard is of very good quality overall, with just a small problem :

The keys "PageUp" and "Origin" are on the same physical key, as well as "PageDown" and "End". The default behavior is to execute "PageUp/PageDown", and I need to hold "FN" to be able to type "End" or "Origin". Not really convenient for a programmer...

Is it possible to swap the FN function just for these particular keys ? I'd like the default behavior to be "End/Origin" and not "PageUp/PageDown"

I am running Windows 10

*The actual laptop is a MSI Ghost GS60*

Comment: Why don't you just map it, using a program like AutoHotKey?

Comment: @Dave Oh right... I feel stupid now =_=. Yeah I'm gonna use SharpKeys for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a software mapping tool, such as AutoHotKey or SharpKeys

Although you know this, I put in for clarity (for other visitors) but the search phrase you need is "

> software keyboard mapping

Or

> keyboard mapping tool

These will usually bring up a wealth of information.